# How can I get the value of a variable from the session storage without refreshing the page in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

Please I'm new to react and I'm trying to set a value on session storage the get it on another page. The problem is, I'm forced to refresh the page to get the updated value stored in the session storage.

I tried setting this way :

```
sessionStorage.setItem("annee", JSON.stringify(annees));
sessionStorage.setItem("commune", JSON.stringify(communes));
```

And getting this other way :

```
{JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("commune")).ctd_name_commune}
{JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("annee")).ctd_annee_libelle}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event listener. When any change is made to storage this function will be triggered. You won't have to refresh the page.

```js
  const handleChange = ({ key, value }) => {
    // Do Something with the key and value key
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      'storage',
      handleChange,
      false,
    );

    return () => window.removeEventListener('storage', handleChange);
  }, []);
```

For better result you can simply create a hook to handle storage similar to state. I have created one for LocalStorage. You can create a similar one for sessionStorage.

[Hook](https://gist.github.com/mehulcse/e72a6839ca53d3a91fa48077250db6bb) Link

**Edit**

If it's on the same tab then we have to dispatch it separately on the same page. It might end up triggering the same twice for other pages but that can be handled conditionally.

To dispatch,

```
window.dispatchEvent( new Event('storage') )
```

More reading on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event)

Comment: This will not work, the `storage` event is not triggered on the active tab.

Comment: That is 100% true. If its on the same tab then we have to dispatch it separately on the same page. It might end up triggering the same twice for other pages but that can be handled conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set something in `sessionStorage` you should be able to get it immediately without refreshing, but only if it's on the same tab. If you are trying to get the data in `sessionStorage` from another tab, then you would always have to refresh, unless you open the tab *after* setting the item. You could do that like this:

```
Promise.resolve( sessionStorage.setItem('test', true) )
    .then(() => {
        window.open(window.location.href, '_blank')
    })
```

Then when you are on this newly opened tab you will be able to access the same data in `sessionStorage`.

Same goes for `localStorage` and cookies. If you're unable to do it like that then I'd suggest storing the data on the server and retrieving it that way.

Read all about `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` here: https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/